# Google map not loading the first time on my Android app

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Strangely, Google map V2 does not load in my Android app Activity the first time I open it. If I close all running apps, including this app, and re-open it, the map is displayed fine. What is it that I might be doing wrong ? Is there any cache to clear on loading the map for the 1st time ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried in other phone?

Comment: Yes, I have. Same issue in that phone as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the cause, not the fix yet. Once I make a SSL call, setting HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory, the Google map load is not working till I close the app and re-open. Now need to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

get an iphone <3. jk i have s7 edge. but have your tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Even without turning it off, if I just clear all running apps, the next time the map loads fine. But if I install my app afresh, the map does not load the 1st time.

Comment: but it loads the second time?

Comment: Yes, it does. Perfectly well. What I mean by 2nd time is when I open my app again AFTER closing it. From that point onwards, it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem. I found the solution. Please see the below details for solution.

**My Old Code which created the issue :**

```
  MapFragment myMapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance();
                        FragmentTransaction tx = activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                        tx.Add(Resource.Id.map, myMapFragment);
                        tx.Commit();
myMapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

**My New Code which solved the issue:**

```
MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)activity.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);

                    myMapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that the issue was related to my setting default SSL SockettFactory at System level. Once I removed it and started to set it only for each call, my maps started to load fine